# Adding and accessing objects in an array (objective c)

Tags: objective-c, arrays, object, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I'm trying to create a little App, tracking my refusing statistics.
Like Consumption, average speed, date of last refueling.. etc.

And after entering these details, adding them to a list sorted by the date.

[Looking something like this!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ1kK.png)

I am able to add new entries to the list on the Left View controller. But I have no Idea how I can create an Object and putting this into an array, and accessing it later on.

If I added the new object to the list, I want to be able to click on it, and change the date or the consumption or anything.

I'm not even sure if I need an Array, or and Dictionary.

If You need some code I have already written, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an array is probably best, so expose an `NSArray` (immutable array), but in the implementation of the class you should use an `NSMutableArray` (mutable array) so that you can add/remove items but you don't want users of the class to be able to do that:

`.h` file:

```
@interface WhatNot : UITableViewController

@property (readonly) NSArray *listOfThings;

...

@end
```

`.m` file:

```
@implementation WhatNot ()
{
    NSMutableArray *_listOfThings;
}
@end

@implementation WhatNot

...

// Override the getter method
- (NSArray *)listOfThings {
    return _listOfThings;
}
```

If you want the user of the class to be able to add objects to the array then provide them with a method to do so, and within that method you can add the object to the array and arrange to update the tableView:

```
- (void)addThing:(Thing *)thing {
    [_listOfThings addObject:thing];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:[_listOfThings count] - 1];   
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView insertRowAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```